# How to display average per grading period in html? using django

Tags: django, django-views

I have this filter that compute the final average per Grading Categories

```
gradepercategory = studentsEnrolledSubjectsGrade.objects.filter(Grading_Categories__in = gradingcategories.values_list('id', flat=True))\
                .filter(grading_Period__in=period.values_list('id', flat=True)).values('Grading_Categories').annotate(average_grade=Avg('Grade'))
```

when i print it, the result is like this:

```
<QuerySet [{'Grading_Categories': 1, 'average_grade': 88.3333333333333}, {'Grading_Categories': 2, 'average_grade': 90.0}]>
```

I just want to display in my html the actual average per grading period in html but the result i got in html is like this

```
<QuerySet [{'Grading_Categories': 1, 'average_grade': 88.3333333333333}, {'Grading_Categories': 2, 'average_grade': 90.0}]>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how you want it displayed in the template, but for example, in a table:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Categories</th>
      <th>Avgerage Grade</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for result in gradepercategory %}
       <tr>
         <td>{{ result.Grading_Categories }}</td>
         <td>{{ result.average_grade }}</td>
       </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: oh thanks sir , it works, sorry i just focus on the terminal result, but thanks anyways